# passing form object and a variable at the same time in jquery post

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

i know this question may be a little out of curiosity but please help me understand because i have done research on this already but may needed an explanation since it wasn't clear enough

is it possible to pass a form object and a variable at the same time in jquery post
for example

```
var review=$('#review').val();
var post_url="url.com";
$.post(post_url,{'review':review, $('#registration_form').serialize()},     function(returned_form)
     {           
         $('#show_items').html(returned_form);
    });
```

can the above code work well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can pass multiple values.  You just need to name each one:

```
var review=$('#review').val();
var post_url="url.com";
$.post(post_url,
       {
         'review': review, 
         'registrationForm' : $('#registration_form').serialize()
       },
       function(returned_form) {           
         $('#show_items').html(returned_form);
       }
);
```